# XML validation not working

Tags: html, xml, xsd

i have one XML file and one XSD file.  i in xsd in set cost as integer value but its not working . i don't know problem in my linking xsd file or where. why it doesn't show any error or warning. if i check this with online validation tool it show an error can anyone help me.

This is my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



<cupcakes xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com cupcake.xsd">
<item>
    <name>Luscious Vanilla</name>
    <flavour>Vanilla</flavour>
    <colour>Brown</colour>
    <energy> 410 KJ </energy>
    <cost> $0.90 sdfgsdfg</cost>
</item>

<item>
    <name>Chocolate Hazelnut</name>
    <flavour>Chocolaty</flavour>
    <colour>Coffe</colour>
    <energy> 350 KJ </energy>
    <cost> $2 </cost>
</item>

<item>
    <name>Risch Red Velvet</name>
    <flavour>Red Velvet</flavour>
    <colour>Red</colour>
    <energy> 105 CAL </energy>
    <cost> $5 </cost>
</item>

<item>
    <name>Classic straberry</name>
    <flavour>Straberry</flavour>
    <colour>Pink</colour>
    <energy> 110 CAL </energy>
    <cost> $6 </cost>
</item>

<item>
    <name>Lemon Drop</name>
    <flavour>Lemon</flavour>
    <colour>Yellow</colour>
    <energy> 510 KJ </energy>
    <cost> $12 </cost>
</item>

 </cupcakes>
```

and this is my XSD file .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
              xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
              elementFormDefault="qualified">
     <xs:element name="cupcakes">
           <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                             <xs:complexType>
                                   <xs:sequence>
                                         <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                         <xs:element name="flavour" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                         <xs:element name="colour" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                         <xs:element name="energy" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                         <xs:element name="cost" type="xs:integer"></xs:element>
                                   </xs:sequence>
                             </xs:complexType>
                       </xs:element>
                 </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>


</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cost items are set to be integer but you are using floating point.

And you are using '$' which is not an integer.

Try this tool:  http://xmlvalidation.com

Comment: i know this i why does it not showing any error .. it should show any error i want the error how i will know that validation is working correctly unless it will not show any error

Comment: What are you using to process the XML file?

Comment: direct opening in mozila browser

Comment: Browsers do not validate XML.  They only format them for viewing.

Comment: thanks can u help me little more ..

i want to set cost range to 1000 how i can do this .. 

<xs:element name="cost" type="xs:integer"></xs:element>

i know i need to give maxlength but i dnt know where